# Difference between the number of lucky numbers and medium numbers

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

**Problem:** Consider all the natural numbers from $000000$ to $999999$. Among these, those numbers with sum of first 3 digits equal to sum of last 3 digits are called lucky. And those with sum of all  the digits equal to $27$ are called medium numbers.

Find the difference between the number of lucky numbers and medium numbers, without using generating functions.

I am being able to do this by generating function method. But it is heavily computational. Also the problem is from the chapter bijections, so there must be a more elegant method to do this.

So, please help.

Comment: There is only $1$ medium number, right?

Comment: @barakmanos No, 909090 and 090909 are both median.

Comment: Oh, so the first part makes the second part confusing. I think you should rewrite "sum of the digits" as "sum of all $6$ digits".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: what happens if you transform each of the first three digits by $d \mapsto 9 - d$?